# vuetify center items into v-flex

Tags: flexbox, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to center a `<v-btn>` into a `<v-flex>`. Since `<v-flex>` is a flexbox div, I use `justify-center` that is transformed into

```css
justify-content: center
```

Since my direction is horizontal, my button should be center aligned but it's not. Here is the codepen that reproduce my problem.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXLzex

I want to signup the button to be centered inside the div (v-flex).

Here is the full code:

```html
<v-card>
  <v-card-text>
    <v-text-field label="Email"></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field label="Password"></v-text-field>
  </v-card-text>

  <v-card-actions>
    <v-layout row>
      <v-flex justify-center>
        <v-btn primary>
          Signup
        </v-btn>
       </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

wrap button inside `<div class="text-xs-center">`

```
<div class="text-xs-center">
  <v-btn primary>
    Signup
  </v-btn>
</div>
```

Dev uses it in his examples.

---

For centering buttons in `v-card-actions` we can add `class="justify-center"`  (note in v2 class is `text-center` (so without `xs`):

```
<v-card-actions class="justify-center">
  <v-btn>
    Signup
  </v-btn>
</v-card-actions>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmPRep)

---

For more examples with regards to centering see [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/centered)

Comment: Thanks that work. But why ?! text-xs-center does a `text-align: center`. Why it doesn't work with flexbox ?

Comment: @Epitouille If you put `d-flex` (`display:flex`) on wrapper, then it will include `flex: 1, 1 auto` on button because of included css: `.d-flex > * { ... flex: 1 1 auto; }`, which will make it full width

Comment: i had to add scoped style `.v-card__actions { 
    display: inline;
}` for properly centering the button on the `v-card-actions` element beside this proposed solution.

Comment: @RakibulHaq We can use `<v-card-actions class="justify-center">`. See edit.

Comment: @Traxo yeah right! i have got rid of that scoped `css` and added **only** the justify-center to the `v-card-actions` and it **works** . thanks man!

Answer (score 20):

```html
<v-layout justify-center>
  <v-card-actions>
    <v-btn primary>
     <span>SignUp</span>
    </v-btn>
  </v-card-actions>
</v-layout>
```

Comment: Please explain how this code works and how it's different than the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me using the v-layout in the following way:

```
<v-layout justify-center>
  <div class="text-center ma-5">
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn primary>
        <span>LogIn</span>
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </div>
</v-layout>
```

vuetify's v-layout allows you to modify all the elements inside the layout.

Answer (score -8):

**v-flex** does not have a display flex!
Inspect v-flex in your browser and you will find out it is just a simple block div.

So, you should override it with `display: flex` in your HTML or CSS to make it work with justify-content.