# Vuetify: How to create fluid footer with centered content?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Right now I am using `v-flex` with a grid of 2 / 8 / 2. So within the 8 is the centered content, but the problem with this is, that it is not centered with the same width as the rest of the website's content. So it there another way to do this?

This is my approach:

```
<v-footer>
    <v-container fluid>

        <v-layout >
            <v-flex md2 ></v-flex>

            <v-flex md8 >
                    My centered content...
            </v-flex>

            <v-flex md2></v-flex>
        </v-layout>

    </v-container>
</v-footer>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vuetify center items into v-flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404884/vuetify-center-items-into-v-flex)

Comment: Provide more info with regards to the "`rest of the website's content`", and what do you mean by "centered". There is no way to guess how the rest of your site looks. Kindly reproduce on codepen. (Unless it's duplicate of the linked question).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! Add `text-xs-center` to `v-flex` and it works

```
<v-footer class="indigo lighten-1">
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-layout >
            <v-flex md2 ></v-flex>
            <v-flex md8  class="white--text pt-0 text-xs-center">
          My centered content...
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex md2></v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</v-footer>
```

> Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/varit05/pen/gEJjja) demo

Hope this helps!