# Center v-switch inside a v-flex

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I would like to center the `v-switch` element inside a `v-flex` horizontally and I already tried this here: [vuetify center items into v-flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404884/vuetify-center-items-into-v-flex), but it seems not to work for the `v-switch` element.

Whether I wrap it inside a div class like this:

```
<v-flex xs12 md2 >
    <div class="text-xs-center">
        <v-switch
            @click="someFunction()"
            label="Some Label Name"
            color="black"
            value="secondary"
            hide-details
        ></v-switch>
    </div>
</v-flex>
```

Or I use the class directly inside the `v-flex`:

`<v-flex xs12 md2 text-xs-center>`

It doesn't work. Also using other classes like `class="justify-center"` doesn't work.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/saitam1/pen/aMeNzb), so you can see the problem

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qvebJB is it what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: no, I need it here: https://codepen.io/saitam1/pen/aMeNzb

Comment: @saitam is [this](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/QoeEjW) what you want?

Comment: @saitam there is also a typo in your codepen: sx12

Comment: @saitam fyi my solution is the same as DjSh, so what was wrong with it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Vuetify version 1.5:**

You can do that using the `<v-layout row wrap justify-center>` instead of `<v-layout column>`. you also need to change `md10` to `md12` so the `v-switch` appears in the center:

```
<v-layout row wrap justify-center>
        <v-flex class="red" xs12 md12>
          Text Text Text <br>
          Text Text Text <br>
          Text Text Text <br>
          Text Text Text <br>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 md2>
                <v-switch
                    @click="SomeFunction"
                    label="Some Label Name"
                    color="black"
                    value="secondary"
                    hide-details
                ></v-switch>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
```

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/djshan/pen/QoeEjW).

**Update:** **Vuetify version 2.0.0:**

```
<v-row wrap justify="center">
   <v-col cols="12" xs="12" md="12" class="red">
       ...
   </v-col>
   <v-col cols="12" xs="12" md="12">
        ...
   </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `class="switch-center"` in `v-switch` tag and write below **CSS** will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
.switch-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.switch-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<v-flex xs12 md2 >
    <div class="text-xs-center">
        <v-switch
            class="switch-center"
            @click="someFunction()"
            label="Some Label Name"
            color="black"
            value="secondary"
            hide-details
        ></v-switch>
    </div>
</v-flex>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply "justify-center" to the "v-layout" tag, which should be found prior to the "v-flex" tag.

```
<v-layout justify-center>
    <v-flex xs12 md2 >
        <v-switch
            @click="someFunction()"
            label="Some Label Name"
            color="black"
            value="secondary"
            hide-details
        ></v-switch>
    </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

EDIT: just saw your codepen in the comments. Assuming you're trying to keep the text aligned to the left while moving the v-switch to the center, try using two different v-layout tags for each v-flex tag.

```
<v-layout column>
    <v-flex xs12 md10>
        TEXT
    </v-flex>
</v-layout>
<v-layout column align-center>
    <v-flex xs12 md2 >
        <v-switch
            @click="SomeFunction"
            label="Some Label Name"
            color="black"
            value="secondary"
            hide-details
        ></v-switch>
    </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```