# How to align the contents to the center of the v-card component in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Currently in the **products.vue**, I have an array of productList containing 4 objects. I will loop through the array and pass each individual objects to the ProductsItem.vue component. In that component, I create the cards using vuetify.

I am unable to align the contents to the centre of the card.

Here is my code, a screenshot of my cards and the desired result

Products.vue

```html
    <template>
      <div>
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <v-container class="my-5">
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4 v-for="productItem in productList" 
    :key="productItem.id">
              <ProductItems :productItem="productItem"/>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import ProductItems from "@/components/ProductItems";


    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          productList: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "Superdry",
              description: "Rookie Aviator Patched Bomber"
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "SuperHot",
              description: "Rookie Aviator Patched Bomber"
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              name: "Buron MensWear",
              description: "Skinny Fit Oxford Shirt In White"
            },
            {
              id: 4,
              name: "Asos",
              description: "slim shirt with stretch in blue"
            }
          ]
        };
      },

        components: {
          ProductItems
        }
      }
    </script>
```

ProductItem.vue

```html
    <template>
      <v-card flat class="ma-3 text-xs-center">
      <v-img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/desert.jpg" aspect- 
    ratio="2.75"></v-img>
        <v-card-title primary-title>
          <div>
            <h3 class="headline pink--text text--accent-2"> 
    {{productItem.name}}</h3>
            <div>{{productItem.description}}</div>
          </div>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn flat color="orange">Add to Cart</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      props: ["productItem"],
      data() {
        return {};
      }
    };
    </script>

<style>
</style>
```

[image: Current result]

Comment: Could you provide a CodePen or JsFiddle please ?

Comment: @Toodoo Sure, give me a second

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vuetify center items into v-flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404884/vuetify-center-items-into-v-flex)

Comment: @Issaki in your codepen the title is centered. Which part you want to centralize?

Comment: @DjSh The product description and button

Comment: @Djsh The title is also not centered when i look at my Codepen though

Answer (score 129, accepted):

**Update** : Works in both version of Vuetify 1.5 and 2:

To centralize `v-card-text` content just apply the `class=text-center`

`v-card-title` and `v-card-actions` are **flex** components so by adding `class="justify-center"` to both you can centralize the whole thing:

```
<v-card-title primary-title class="justify-center">
  <div>
    <h3 class="headline pink--text text--accent-2">Superdry</h3>
    <div>Rookie Aviator Patched BomberproductItem.description</div>
  </div>
</v-card-title>
<v-card-actions class="justify-center">
  <v-btn flat color="orange">Add to Cart</v-btn>
</v-card-actions>
```

Comment: you are welcome. Actually you dont even need `class="text-xs-center"` so I removed it from my answer

Answer (score 4):

> you can also use **v-spacer** to center components in ***both*** **v-card-title** and **v-card-text** of a **v-card**

> **Works on both 1.5.x and 2.x**

```
<v-card-title>
  <v-spacer />
  <div class="text-center">
    <h3 class="headline pink--text text--accent-2">Headline</h3>
    <div>Some description about the headline</div>
  </div>
  <v-spacer />
</v-card-title>
<v-card-actions>
  <v-spacer />
  <v-btn color="orange">Some Button</v-btn>
  <v-spacer />
</v-card-actions>
```

Here are sandboxes for quick demonstration

**For 1.5.x**  
https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-1-5-v-spacer-f7s0ek?file=/src/App.vue

**For 2.x**  
https://codesandbox.io/s/v-spacer-for-vuetify-2-x-bsi9x8?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thank you so much for coming up with the `v-spacer` solution! Every once in a while I have alignment issues in different contexts and every time I reserach solutions someone who mentions the spacer saves my ass :-D